# How to allow URLs in robots.txt but disallow other ones similar to allowed

Tags: robots.txt

This is what I'm using now:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Allow: /video/funny-dogs/index.html
Allow: /video/funny-cats/index.html
Allow: /video/funny-dolphins/index.html
Disallow: /video/
```

But seems like all others "/video/" URLs are also being crawled.

What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You robots.txt file should definitely work for Google, and I believe it will work for Bing. However, for many other robots it probably won't work, because not all robots prioritize competing Allows & Disallows the same way. Also, some robots don't support Allow at all.

For robots other than Google/Bing, you can increase the chances of success by removing the "Allow: /" line. Many older robots look for the first directive that can be applied to the current URL and then stop looking. For these robots, the allow will always be applied, and the other directives will always be ignored. Removing the "Allow: /" should fix this.

If Google or Bing are not obeying your robots.txt file, then something may be broken. You might check for the following things:

- Was the robots.txt file added/changed very recently? Google can often take as much as a week to notice a new robots.txt file.
- Is the robots.txt in the site's root directory? (e.g. in http://somesite.com/robots.txt, NOT http://somesite.com/subdir/robots.txt)
- Do requests for the robots.txt file return anything funny in the response headers, like X-Robots-Tag:noindex, or a status code other than 200?

Answer (score 1):

The original robots.txt specification said that the bot should read robots.txt and take the first rule that applies. When `Allow` was added, that wasn't changed, and many bots still use that rule. Other bots use the most permissive rule.

In the first case, `Allow: /` on the first line of the file will cause the bot to think that it can crawl. In the second case, the existence of `Allow: /` *anywhere* in the file will cause the bot to assume that it can crawl anything.

There is never a good reason to include `Allow: /`. The assumption in robots.txt is that if a file isn't specifically disallowed, then crawling is allowed. `Allow` is intended to be an override or exception to a `Disallow`.

Remove the `Allow: /`. Things should work then.